# How to write mapper and reducer for Euclidean distance

Tags: hadoop

I am totally new in big data, actually, I wrote a code which is computing Euclidean distance in Python ( 10000 points).Now, I want to run it in Hadoop but I don't know how to write mapper and reducer because I could not find anything in Google and all the tutorials are about word-count.

Comment: Could you give a sample of input data and expected output?

Comment: The input data could be any number  in range of (0,100) as 2D dimensional .i.e (34,45)  which would be saved in tab delimited file, the expected output would be ucleadian distance of 10000 points from the origin (0,0), my question is " should I put the distance calculator in mapper? or reducer?

Comment: Thank you for the response-- would you tell me how to write mapper?

Comment: I know how to split the input --- for line in sys.stdin fields = line.split(","), but from here I dont know how to put ucleadian distance calculator in Mapper.